# Проверка url React

Tags: reactjs, router

В методе render() хочу сделать проверку типа:

```
render() {
    return (    
        if ("/order")
            <div>Order</div>
        else
            <div>Not Order</div>
    )
}
```

Т.е. проверить, если url /order то выводить одно, иначе другое. Использую React Router.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В четвертой версии каждый дочерний компонент `Route` получает и `match` в props. Ваша проверка может выглядить так:

```
if(props.match.path === '/order')
     ....
```

Так же в объекте `match` есть атрибут `url`. В url `/order` отличий между ними не увидеть и `url` и `path` вернут одно и то же значение.
Но если url выглядит как `/order/:id` то `path` вернет значение записанное в `Route`, т.е `/order/:id`, а `url` вернет реальный url, к примеру `/order/42`

Comment: А если у меня "react-router": "2.4.0". Я поменял на "4.2.0", у меня все сломалось.

Comment: @ks_on_v конечо все сломается, 4я версия обратно не совместима. Посмотрите, что передается в `props`, объект `location` там должен быть

Comment: location - undefined. Там только Dispatch.

Comment: Помог вот этот пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010053/react-router-this-props-location. this.props.location доступен в Route компонентах.